# ram not detected by tensorflow gpu

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, ram

I recently add a 8gb ram to my computer to facilitate computing, however the gpu tensorflow doesn't seem to recognize it even though my ubuntu recognize it. Here's my result after running `sudo lshw -class memory`

and the result is

```
  *-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 2c
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 16GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
      product: HMA81GS6AFR8N-UH
      vendor: 009C35230000
      physical id: 0
      serial: 31D92036
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: SODIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
      product: CT8G4SFS824A.C8FAD1
      vendor: 009D36160000
      physical id: 1
      serial: 156C0B48
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
```

However, the gpu tensorflow doesn't recognize it and still output as following

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.645
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.66GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating 
TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
```

Is there any extra steps I need to do to get my full ram recognized?

Answer (score 0):

GPU RAM and system RAM are two different and separate things